# Adjective complement before or after the noun

Tags: adjectives, post-modifier

Consider:

1. > We are seeking (looking for) people skilled in mathematics.
2. > A different life from this one.

How we should place the adjective complements correctly, I mean how to distinguish that we should use pattern 1 or 2?

I know that below structures are wrong:

3. > - We are seeking (looking for) skilled people in mathematics .
4. > - We are seeking (looking for) skilled in mathematics people .
5. > - A different from this one life .

---

**Q1** : Is there any specific rule that can help me categorize these sentences; For example, I say: " Ok, I want to be understood and discerned in this way  so, I must use pattern 1(2) " or "Since there is Past participle I must do like what has been done in 1"

**Q2** : If the answer of the **Q1** is **No**, then I must memorize how many phrases ? It is annoying for an English learner.

Thanks

Comment: I'd rather use "*A life **different from this one***" for (2).

Comment: Also, use of *for* after the verb *seek* is unconventional.  Usually no preposition is needed for it.  Should be "*We are seeking people ...*"

Comment: Give me one grammatically correct example where '*seek*' is used with '*for*' please.

Comment: Victor's right, it is awkward and unnecessary there.  I'm not sure if it is really incorrect.  @VictorBazarov "I seek for you an item most rare." ;)

Comment: @goldilocks.  Yes, I thought of a similar example, but in that case '*an item*' is the direct object and '*for you*' is indirect one.  In all examples given there are no indirect objects, I think.

Comment: @Cardinal In *they seek solace for* the preposition is linked to the noun *solace*, not the verb. And the phrase *sought for provisions* is incorrect. You can say *sought provisions* or *looked for provisions*.

Comment: @Cardinal:  It ***is*** relevant if you want to learn. A search for (in quotes) "sought for provisions" gives a mere **14** results, which is in no way a proof of correctness. The phrase "*seek solace*" has the object without the preposition.

Comment: @Cardinal What I did find was *Consent sought for....is...* That phrase is in the passive, *consent **is** sought* and the for-phrase is the goal for which that consent is sought.

Comment: @VictorBazarov I have said i changed it. OK, I edit it right now ! So, Can we talk about the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Seek for* is not idiomatic English and is a contamination of *to look for* and *to seek*. You *seek something* or you *seek to do something*, but the preposition *for* is not normally used in combination with the verb seek. You could say:

> - We are **seeking** people skilled in mathematics.
> - We are **looking for** people skilled in mathematics.

Here is an example of *seek + to infinitive*:

> We **seek *to expand*** our collection.

In your second sentence, the adjective *different* should follow *life*, because *from this one* modifies *different* and not *life*. Therefore, you should attach it to the adjective instead of splitting the postmodifier into a pre- and postmodifier by putting *life* in between:

> A life different from this one.

There is a difference in usage for pre- and postmodifiers. Premodifiers precede the main noun of your phrase and are normally not too long. Having a long premodifier makes it more difficult to read the phrase. Often, long modifiers are put after the main noun as a postmodifier (although in scientific writing you can still find long premodifiers).

In your example *different from this one* is a rather long phrase, which is why you should use it as a postmodifier rather than a premodifier. If you only use the adjective *different*, you can use that as a premodifier. Simple adjectives are often put in the premodifier and longer phrases, such as relative clauses, are used as postmodifiers.

So, in your phrase with *skilled*, avoid a long premodifier:

> We are seeking people skilled in mathematics.

In any case, do not split your adjective from other phrases that are modifying it:

> We are seeking skilled people in mathematics.

In the above sentence, *skilled* still modifies *people*, but *in mathematics* no longer modifies *skilled*. As a result, you're saying that *in mathematics* is the **location** where you will be looking for *skilled people*.

Both of your sentences with long premodifiers sound odd. If you have no postmodifier, don't put in a long premodifier. You could perhaps make your premodifier slightly longer if your postmodifier is already terribly long, but in general the premodifier restricts itself often to just some adjectives, except for scientific writing as I mentioned earlier:

> - We seek **a** *much more pleasant* **life** *different from this one*.
> - We seek **a** *much more pleasant* **life** *that is totally different from this one*.
> - We seek *extraordinarily qualified* **people** *skilled in mathematics*.
> - We seek *extraordinarily qualified* **people** *who are skilled in mathematics*.

Note how the premodifier more or less restricts itself to adjectives (and adverbs) while relative clauses, gerunds and other phrases often go in the postmodifier. In all four of the sentences above, the premodifier could be moved and used as a postmodifier whereas it would not really work the other way around.

Additionally, it sounds rather odd to mention *from this one* **before** you mention *life*.

In short, don't make your premodifier too long, it will not improve readability. Restrict it to mostly adjectives and perhaps adverbials modifying those adjectives. Longer phrases should go in the postmodifier.